# Calling external secure rest APIs from a Sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, form, api

I am very new to Sharepoint and normally code using JS and Angular.  I would like to create a form that is hosted in SharePoint.  The form will collect some simple data (name and a few other fields) and then will call an external third party service that returns a security token.  I then would like to make a second call to the service passing the security token along with some of the form data.  Is there a recommended way of doing this in Sharepoint.  I have installed Sharepoint 2013 and I have Visual Studio Community Edition.  Thank you and my apologies for the beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint is a Client Side Application calling an HTTPS endpoint,
No difference with any other Web application.

So SharePoint is the Host for your familiar JS/Angular code,
SharePoint is your webserver, just like IIS or Apache or xxxx is

You add your code:

- into a Content Editor Web Part
- into a Script Webpart
- as Script Source in a Page
- referenced by a SCRIPT tag in an (ASPX) (Master)Page
- referenced by an ASPX ScriptLink Tag in a (Master)Page

Good developers use code:

- referenced by JSLink (must see: https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor)

  - from a Field
  - from a View
  - from a Web Part (must see: https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar)
- referenced by a UserCustomAction ScriptLink (must see: https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor)
- and I probably forgot one

Modern Developers **also** use the SharePoint Framework

- https://youtu.be/3ACJ8MG1yTU

If you are coming from a SharePoint Background this SharePoint Framework is hot & happing, cool & awesome

If you have been in the normal Web world for the past years you will agree:

*WTF! we have used all these NPM and Gulp and whatnot technologies for the past X years,

What?! is so new about this?*

It is Microsoft finally catching up with the real Web world...
remember; most of SharePoints Server side code dates back 10 to 20 years

---

> With the SharePoint FrameWork anyone with up to date Web skills
>   (React, Angular etc) will be a better developer than those SharePoint
>   .Net heads who now need to learn Front-End

Comment: Danny,  Thank you so much.  I will take a closer look and check out the links that you have provided.   I want to make sure I don't hit any CORS issues and make sure I understand the right approach (Provider hosted versus Sharepoint-hosted) and other factors.  Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: CORS is server side controlled, so if you call an API **from SharePoint**, that server needs to allow (cross-origin) access. Calling a SharePoint API **from the outside world** is a whole different story. Look into SharePoint & ADAL. Also take a look at the Microsoft Graph (API into all Office365 Apps like Outlook etc.)

Comment: Hi Danny, In this case it would be calling an API from Sharepoint.   Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if it using the Cross-Domain Library would make sense for my use-case.

Comment: Don't know what you mean with CDL. You can call any HTTPS endpoint from SharePoint provided that server allows Cross Origin access. See the PnP Core JS library, that abstracts the (native JavaScript Fetch API) It's a standalone library so not tied to SPFx